# Simulate birth with Rstudio - draw pmf and cdf

Tags: r, cdf

I have a little exercise to solve with Rstudio for my statistics exam.
I tryed to translate it in english, so if something isn't clear please ask me for explanations.

"Simulate 100,000 births and use the following probabilities: males 51.3%, females 48.7%, using the **sample** function.

- Check how much the number of males and females obtained differ from the theoretical percentages.
- Draw the PMF and the CDF of the probability function of this experiment (on a sample of 50 births).
- Calculate mean and variance of the distribution."

I obtained 51356 males and 48644 females, a difference of 56.

**But now, How can I draw PMF and CDF of the probability function?**

Here I put the code used to simulate the births:

```
mysample <- data.frame(sample(c("M","F"),100000,replace=T,prob=c(0.513,0.487)))
names(mysample)<-c("Gender")
males <- subset(mysample, Gender=="M")
females <- subset(mysample,Gender=="F")

theoricM <- 100000*0.513
theoricF <- 100000*0.487
realM <- as.integer(nrow(maschi))
realF <- as.integer(nrow(femmine))

#create a data frame to show differences
result <-data.frame(realM,theoricM,realF,theoricF)
names(result)<- c("Males","Theoric Males","Females","Theoric Females")
```

And results:

[image]

Hope someone could help me, I know it's a very easy question for someone experienced with R, but I'm at the very beginning with this language.

So thank you to everyone who will reply.

**EDIT:**

I tried this code:

```
x <- 1:50
plot(x,dbinom(x ,size = 50,prob = 0.513),type="l", ylab="PMF", main="Binomial Distribution PMF")
```

And the result is:

[image]

What I think I understand is that, being the prob very close to 1/2, on a set of 50 births the number of males will be very close to 25. Is what plot is showing? And, is this the correct way to do that?

Comment: hints: `?table`, `?cumsum`

Comment: Sorry I can't understand, could you please explain better?

Comment: I'm unwilling to give you too much help on an exam.  Actually, in re-reading the question I think you should look at `?dbinom` (you're being asked to plot the *theoretical* sampling distribution, not the observed distribution from a large number of simulations).

Comment: This is not the exam (of course!), it is an exercise in preparation for the exam; so I have to learn how to solve it to pass the exam. 
However, I had already intuited it was binomial distribution, I can not understand how to create the theoretical pmf; for example in this code:  how can I set that the possible choices are only two (M and F)    
`x <- 1:50   
plot(x,dbinom(x ,size = 50,prob = c(0.513,0.487)),type="l", ylab="PMF", main="Binomial Distribution PMF")`
I tried something like this `data <- sample(c("M","F"),50,replace=T,prob=c(0.513,0.487))` instead of x, but it's non numeric

Comment: you should add this stuff to your question, so that it's clearer what you tried.  (You're close.) Hint #2: for a binomial, you don't need to specify both probabilities -- just the probability of whichever outcome you're counting as "success".  (The problem would be a lot harder for a multinomial distribution with >2 categories ...)

Comment: Ok, I followed your hints and I edited my question. Check it now. Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code (and conclusion) look correct to me.

It might be graphically better to use `type="h"` to draw a "high-density" plot; this makes it clearer that there is zero probability for non-integer values of `x`.

```
x <- 1:50
par(las=1,bty="l") ## cosmetic
plot(x,dbinom(x ,size = 50,prob = 0.513),type="h", ylab="PMF", 
     main="Binomial Distribution PMF")
```

[image]

(When you plot the CDF/CMF, you may want to use `type="s"` or `type="S"`; see `?plot`)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I'll keep in mind your advices.